# How to extract rows based on two conditions

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have a dataset d1.

```
import pandas as pd
d1 = {
'customers': pd.Series([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]),
'channel': pd.Series(['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']),
'freq': pd.Series([3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
}
d1=pd.DataFrame(d1)
```

I want to get list of customers who have used only two distinct channels and channels 'a' is mandatory.

For ex.. 1st customer has used two distinct channels 'a'& 'b'
2nd customer had used 'a' & 'c' 3rd customer used 'a' & 'b'. But customer 4 has not used channel 'a' and so on....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little convuluted but basically we perform multiply filters on the df using groupby, filtering and 2 levels of boolean indexing:

```
In [140]:
    d1[d1.customers.isin(d1[d1.channel=='a'].customers)].groupby('customers').filter(lambda x: x['channel'].nunique() == 2)
Out[140]:
  channel  customers  freq
0       a          1     3
1       a          1     3
2       b          1     3
3       c          2     2
4       a          2     2
5       a          3     2
6       b          3     2
```

Breaking this down:

```
In [141]:
# filter out just those that have channel a
d1[d1.channel=='a']
Out[141]:
  channel  customers  freq
0       a          1     3
1       a          1     3
4       a          2     2
5       a          3     2
In [144]:
# we want these customer ids
d1[d1.channel=='a'].customers
Out[144]:
0    1
1    1
4    2
5    3
Name: customers, dtype: int64
In [146]:
# perform an additional filtering so we only want customers who have channel a
d1[d1.customers.isin(d1[d1.channel=='a'].customers)]
Out[146]:
  channel  customers  freq
0       a          1     3
1       a          1     3
2       b          1     3
3       c          2     2
4       a          2     2
5       a          3     2
6       b          3     2
```

The above is then groupby'd on customer and then we can apply a filter where the number of unique (nunique) customers is equal to 2

Answer (score 0):

To take it a bit more slowly, e.g. if you plan to complicate the filtering logic further, this is an alternative (and admittedly less elegant) approach which tries not to be a one-liner:

```
def func(x):
    vals = x['channel'].value_counts()
    if 'a' in vals and len(vals) == 2:
        return True
    return False

mask = d1.groupby('customers').apply(func)
print mask
```

Output:

```
customers
1             True
2             True
3             True
4            False
dtype: bool
```

Now it depends on how you want the output to be:

```
# Get a list of customers, like
# [1, 2, 3]
target_customers = [k for k, v in mask.to_dict().iteritems() if v]

# Get a slice of the original DataFrame
print d1[d1['customers'].isin(target_customers)]
```